# Custom Eclipse Shortcut doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, subversive, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to attribute a custom shortcut key in Eclipse Kepler. It's for the Base from Working Copy in the Compare context menu any give file (via right click). This screenshot shows how it's been setup:

[image]

Pressing that key combination does absolutely nothing. ATM, other Compare sub menu commands are working fine (ie. CTRL+ALT+L). When I right click on a file > Compare, I can see the assigned shortcut in the context menu.

I've restarted Eclipse after assigning the shortcut to make sure it "takes" properly. Still to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of other commands also registered for the same short cut i.e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Please do verify how many commands are registered for the short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, by typing the **"CTRL+ALT+L"** text in the search box below the **Scheme** combo box.

If multiple command are registered then change the short of your command so that it become unique, then try the command and verify the result.

Comment: Only one shortcut for Ctrl+Alt+W, which is what I setup originally.

Comment: If only single command is registered for `Ctrl+Alt+W` short cut then try to change the options in **When** text box(refer screen shot) instead of "window" choose "In <xyz view>" or "Editor <java/c/> source". Restart is not required to take effect of these changes.

Comment: I've gone ahead and tried various combinations but none of them end up working. So, Ctrl+Alt+W shows up as the assigned command to Base from Working Copy (only When is In Windows), but it doesn't do anything. However, other nearby assigned commands work fine (ie. Ctrl+Alt+L - compare using latest revision). At this point, I can access this by doing a right click > Compare > Base from Working Copy...

Comment: Try to change the **Scheme** from **Default** to others then check, also I suggest to install the latest  version of SVN plugin. It may be a bug in SVN plugin.

Comment: You might also want to ensure that the Handler for the command is enabled, it's possible that it's trying to execute but since the handler is 'disabled' it gives up...